# SQL Syntax error in C# string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, webforms, ado.net

I'm running a query from a web form to update records. Since I'm just learning about C#, I'm using a command string as opposed to a stored procedure.

My update method is as follows:

```
public void updateOne()
    {
        string commandText = "update INVOICE SET <Redacted> = @<Redacted>, 
                    Supplier = @Sup, SupplierName = @SupN, NetTotal = @Net, 
                              VATTotal = @VAT, InvoiceDate = @InvDt "
       <needed a line break here, which is why I split the string again> 
                              + "WHERE K_INVOICE = @K_INV";

        using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection
                                                    (conParams.connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, dbConnection);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@K_INV", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@K_INV"].Value = @K_INV;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@<Redacted>", @<Redacted>.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sup", @Sup.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupN", @SupN.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Net", @Net.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("VAT", @VAT.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InvDt", @InvDt.ToString());

            try
            {
                dbConnection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                errorString = e.Message.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

`Catch` stalls on an SQL error (Incorrect syntax near SET), and I have an idea that the issue occurs because I convert the parameters to strings. The first parameter is an Int, which should be OK.

If this is the case, what should I convert the parameters to? If not, what on earth is wrong?

Comment: Is your column name `<Redacted>` contains `<>` that might be the problem in your query.

Comment: you do not need the `@` Literal symbol in your second param for the addwithvalue. what's `< >` used for in your Param..?

Comment: @Habib no, this is a placeholder since the column name may identify my organisation

Comment: @marc_s does this imply that I need to convert all the strings to a c# type that corresponds to the SQL type?

Comment: No - instead of `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SupN", @SupN.ToString());` just use `cmd.Parameters.Add("@SupN", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = ........;`

Comment: Can you show where you define and initialize the variables used to pass the values for your parameters? They seems to have some odd names (@K_INV, etc...)

Comment: @marc_s can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you read this blog article on the dangers of `.AddWithValue()`:

- [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Instead of

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sup", @Sup.ToString());
```

you should use

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Sup", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = ...(provide value here)..;
```

(*is your variable in C# really called `@SupN` ?? Rather unusual and confusing....*)

I would recommend to always define an explicit *length* for any string parameters you define

Comment: On the same line: [How Data Access Code Affects Database Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236412.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Try to add a `@` before the string to [escape the breaklines](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma), for sample:

```
string commandText = @"update INVOICE SET [Redacted] = @Redacted, 
                    Supplier = @Sup, SupplierName = @SupN, NetTotal = @Net, 
                              VATTotal = @VAT, InvoiceDate = @InvDt "
                              + "WHERE K_INVOICE = @K_INV";
```

In parameterName argument you can add the @ but the value not, just the variable, for sample

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Redacted", redacted.ToString());
```

Try to execute this query in the databse with some values to check if everything is correct. You could use `[brackets]` in the table name and column names if you have a reserved word.

Comment: I now have no error, but the record doesn't save. Could this be something to do with session data?

Comment: By the way, I need to remove the segments that I edited, as they could potentially identify the organisation I am apprenticing with

Comment: Thankyou, appreciated

Comment: Ah, I understand now. The string itself is named @<stringname>. This is also part of a larger naming convention, and as such I'd need to re-write half of my program. I did write a quick program to try this out, but it made no difference.

Comment: The `@` is a char to escape strings in C#. You do not need to use it in variables like you did in parameters. The marc_s' anwser also help you.